# Can not pre-annotate my documents with rule-based model and dictionary pre-annotater at the same time

Tags: annotations, watson-knowledge-studio

I upload a document and then I create an annotation set which name is A. Firstly, I run my rule-based model to A, and it does work when I continue annotate it in my task. However, if I delete the task, and pre-annotate A with my dictionary which I built before, it is only pre-annotate the dictionary without any rule-based pre-annotation in a new task. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation on pre-annotation. See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/knowledge-studio/preannotation.html#important-notes

> You can run one pre-annotator on documents only. If you run one pre-annotator, and then run a second pre-annotator, the second run will strip the annotations that were added by the first pre-annotator from the documents. Pick the pre-annotation method that best fits your use case, and use that one only.